# How to align and to distance td values

Tags: html, css, database, alignment

My HTML table is like this one:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123 - 20 - 20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The values are retrieved from a db and so are shown as this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWtvS.jpg

How can I have all values (all the numbers) well aligned?
Thanks

Comment: Put each number in its own cell

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to format each "substring" (each number and operator) as it's own table cell, and apply `text-align: center` to every cell. This will keep everything aligned in the center, regardless of how many digits the number has.

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>27.082</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.905</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13.602</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>43715</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>513</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>312</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With a lot of digits, you can see that everything still stays aligned:

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>27.082</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.905</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13.602</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>43750311251242145</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>5313451413</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>31434132</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately, as the code is structured, I can only use a cell in which to insert the 3 values (as in my pic). Are there no other solutions?

Comment: You would need a code-based solution to interpret strings. Because it's all 1 HTML element, you wouldn't be able to use CSS to do it. You would essentially need to add whitespaces on the left and right ends of the string to align the strings. For example, if you have a number "123456" with 6 digits and a number "12" with 2 digits, you would want to add 2 whitespace characters on both sides of the "12" string to align it, such as "--12-- ", where the dashes would be whitespaces. You could do this in JavaScript, but it would be quite lengthy and difficult.